# Docker throwing "{binary} not found" error

Tags: docker, go

I have a very simple Go app that I'm trying to Dockerize.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", date)
    http.HandleFunc("/health", healthCheck)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func healthCheck(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "I'm alive!")
}

func date(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    now := time.Now()
    fmt.Fprintf(w, now.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.14.6

RUN mkdir /app
COPY date.go /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN go build date.go

RUN groupadd -g 999 appuser && \
    useradd -r -u 999 -g appuser appuser
USER appuser

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ['/app/date']
```

However, when I use `docker run` to run the app, I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [/app/date]: not found
```

I've commented out the `CMD ['/app/date']` line and rebuilt the image, and then was able to exec into it by running

```
docker run -dit goapp
docker exec -ti [containerid] /bin/bash
```

This takes me into the /app folder where I do see the date file.  And I am able to run /app/date without any issues.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CMD` is interpreted as JSON, so you need to change the single quotes to double quotes.

```
CMD ["/app/date"]
```

This is specified in the [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> The exec form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you must use double-quotes (") around words not single-quotes (').

Comment: Oh wow - I've been banging my head against this for an hour and (of course) it's something so simple.  This worked for me.

Comment: Great! If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the green checkmark.

Comment: StackOverflow apparently makes you wait a bit before an answer can be accepted :)